# I am trying to unzip bz2 file but then I get the error saying No space left

Tags: partitioning, disk-usage

```
bzip2 -dk a.osm.bz2

bzip2: I/O or other error, bailing out.  Possible reason follows.
bzip2: No space left on device
    Input file = a.osm.bz2, output file = a.osm
bzip2: Deleting output file a.osm, if it exists.
```

I did a `df -h` and

```
Filesystem                         Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv  439G  115G  302G  28% /
/dev/sda2                          976M  104M  806M  12% /boot
....
```

the file is around 100GB. And, I should definitely have around 350GB of free storage. I don't get why it is causing an error.

```
$du -sh a.osm.bz2
100G    a.osm.bz2

$ df -h .
Filesystem                         Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv  439G  121G  295G  30% /
```

Comment: Please instead of `df -h`, add the output of `df -h .` in the same directory as the file. And `du -sh osm.bzw2`. But: If the bz2-file is 100gb, it can be much bigger than 302G and the error would be reasonable.

Comment: Aside, you've got less than the 350 GB free that you think you do - there's only 295 GB free in the latter df output.

Comment: You should be able to ask bzip2 to output the size of the uncompressed file.

Comment: [Is there a way to determine the decompressed size of a .bz2 file?](https://superuser.com/q/53984/113004)

Comment: Doesn't seem like it's the issue here, but if you were extracting a tar file that contained many small files, I have seen errors where the actual error is out of inodes (df -i) but the error message is still saying out of space (what was real fun was when I ran out of inodes which caused an app to spam its log file with out of space error messages until I actually did run out of log space for reals)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It's a big world ;-) The error is reasonable.

From https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Planet.osm:

> on 2021-02-01, the plain OSM XML variant takes over **1370.5 GB** when uncompressed from the 99.3 GB bzip2-compressed downloaded data file).

You could ...

- get more disk space
- download osm files for only the [regions](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Planet.osm#Worldwide_extract_sources) you really need
- for small regions, [use the API](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Downloading_data).
- use [`osmosis`](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmosis) to extract the needed data from the *planet.osm*  file yourself. But instead of the `.bz2` file, you should use the [`pbf` version](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/PBF_Format) , which will be much faster.

Comment: This is a good answer that answer's OP's specific need, but doesn't give a general method for future readers for other files.  I've added that in a supplementary answer.

Comment: 1.3TB XML document sounds like an abuse of XML to me.

Comment: I read like you need 130GB of storage and purchased just 500GB SSD. I was so happy to host my own map server until, this! hahaha

Comment: @Joshua Right. That's why OSM switched from XML to PBF many years ago. XML is still present since some tools don't support PBF yet. However XML is considered legacy and should be avoided, especially for large dumps.

Answer (score 7):

With some time you could figure out how big the files in the archive are, from the archive file itself.

```
-rw------- 1 criggie criggie 95M Jul 22  2015 home-email.tar.bz2

$ bzcat home-email.tar.bz2 | wc -c 
149606400
```

So that 95 MB archive expanded to **149,606,400 bytes** in one tar file, which is enough info for your purposes.

---

In the unix world, compression can be a different process to archiving, which is why we have `gzip` and `bzip2`, and separately have `tar` for sticking things together.

You could dig inside an expanded tar file with test and verbose flags

```
$ bzcat home-email.tar.bz2 | tar -tv
...big list of output....
```

---

An archiver/compressor like `zip` combines the two functions, so had your archive been a `zip` or an `arc` or a `lhz` etc that originated in the PC world, you would have to check the flags for a LIST option - example :

```
$ unzip -lv /home/criggie/config.zip
Archive:  /home/criggie/config.zip
 Length   Method    Size  Cmpr    Date    Time   CRC-32   Name
--------  ------  ------- ---- ---------- ----- --------  ----
       0  Stored        0   0% 2020-07-28 17:04 00000000  dir/
    1708  Defl:N     1093  36% 2017-02-15 14:15 7c7aee5a  dir/file1.txt
    5354  Defl:N     2860  47% 2020-03-10 15:57 31be4459  dir/file2.txt
--------          -------  ---                            -------
  319022            10362  26%                            20 files
```

Comment: Some archive formats like gzip, xz, and zstd have room for metadata indicating the uncompressed size, so you can much more quickly find that.  (e.g. `7z l foo.gz` works for many file types, or `zstd -l foo.zstd` for example.  The header might not be valid for files compressed from a pipe or other stream, and for gzip you can concat gzipped files to make one valid .gz but the header will only be from the first.  Also gzip is only a 32-bit size, IIRC.  IDK about similar limitations in other formats.

Comment: But anyway, yeah `bzcat | wc -c` seems to be the only option for size-finding.  Or just watch `df -h .` while decompression is running.